# Safari extra left input padding

Tags: css, google-chrome, input, safari

http://screencast.com/t/ltPiCJwBaqT

Is it possible to remove this one pixel in safari?
Both fields doesn't have any css applied

Answer (score 0):

You can style the input with padding:

```
input {
    padding-left: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
}
```

If you haven't styled it, the browser assumes the standard styles, and it may differ from browser to browser (as you have noted).

My example above will need to be tweeked, and you may even need to add more or less padding.

Comment: this solution changes (adds) the padding both in safari and chrome

Comment: @Mirek I said that you need to tweek it, change it to 0 for the left padding.

Comment: I said that it changes padding in Safari and in Chrome, I need to have the same space between border and input value in all browsers, padding 0 looks like not styled input